# How to use AutoFixture to generate specific values when the Builder is given an abstract class

Tags: c#, .net, autofixture

I'm trying to generate specific values for a class with AutoFixture but the `Builder` is given an `abstract` class. As such, the builder can't see the properties for either concrete types ... and therefore cannot/doesn't know when/how to create them.

e.g.

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    // Common properties.
    public string Id { get; set }
    public Baa Baa { get; set; }
}

public class ConcreteA : BaseClass
{
    public string Name { get; set ;}
}

public class ConcreteB : BaseClass
{
    public NumberOfPeople int { get; set }
}
```

So, when I create a fake instance of a BaseClass, I'm hoping to set the concrete value, where appropriate.

e.g.

```
Class      | Property and value, to set.
----------------------------------------
ConcreteA  | Name = "Jane"
ConcreteB  | NumberOfPeople = 3
```

I'm not sure how to define (in the `Builder`) that when `currentType == typeof(ConcreteA) then do this...` etc.

#### Update

This is how I am currently creating my fake instances:

```
public static T CreateAThing<T>() where T : BaseClass, new()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    return fixture.Build<T>()
        .With(x => x.Id, $"things-{fixture.Create<int>()}")
        .Create();
}
```

where the `Id` is a consecutive number appended to some fixed string.

Now, when `T` is a `ConcreteA`, then I was hoping to have it do some specific logic. (like set the name to be some first name + surname) while if `T` is a `ConcreteB`, then some random number from 1 to 10.

NOTE: The reason I was doing it like this, was because I was just thinking about not repeating myself for the baseclass properties (like how I'm wanting the `Id` property to be `things-<consecutive number>`.

Open to *all* ideas :)

Comment: Given that you're asking to create an instance of a base object, how would it be possible to get instances of derived objects filled in as well?

Comment: What's wrong with `fixture.Create<ConcreteA>()` and `fixture.Create<ConcreteB>()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27247114/126014

Comment: Updated OP with an example about how i'm using Autofixture to create my concrete's.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can customize each concrete type individually:

```
fixture.Customize<ConcreteA>(c => c.With(x => x.Name, "Jane"));
fixture.Customize<ConcreteB>(c => c.With(x => x.NumberOfPeople, 3));
```

Subsequently, you can simply create them:

```
var a = fixture.Create<ConcreteA>();
var b = fixture.Create<ConcreteB>();

Console.WriteLine(a.Name);
Console.WriteLine(b.NumberOfPeople);
```

Prints:

```
Jane
3
```

Comment: Gotcha -- or use `ICustomization` along with `CompositeCustomization` if i wish to reuse these cusomized concretes in multiple tests, right?

Comment: @Pure.Krome Correct. This answer, however, doesn't provide any information on how to translate a base class into a concrete class, but if you need that, then [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27247689/126014) explains how to do that.